# Flutter: Undefined class 'OSNotificationOpenedResult' and 'OSNotificationReceivedEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, onesignal, dart-pub

after recent onesignal update i get 3 errors:

The getter 'shared' isn't defined for the type 'OneSignal'.

Undefined class 'OSNotificationOpenedResult'.
Undefined class 'OSNotificationReceivedEvent'.

I tried to search similar problems but cannot find anything to help

Comment: You need to update your one signal package. It is probably outdated. You can take a look into their migration guide: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/blob/user_model/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md

Probably this issue is being tracked on git: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/711

Comment: old version works fine, but new doesn't. i have 5.0.2

Comment: Yes. That means these class/methods are no longer available in the new library. You need to migrate/change your code to the latest OneSignal version. So just follow the migration guide and change your code accordingly. If you face problems during the migration, feel free to ask another question (add your relevant codes).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
_handleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
```

to

```
_handleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationClickEvent result)
```

You no longet use shared

```
  OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);
  OneSignal.initialize("APPID");
  OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
```

for even

```
OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
  handleNotification(event.notification.additionalData);
});
```